# dstack with no multiple layers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have the following dataset with a numeric outcome and several columns that represent tags for the numeric outcome

```
outcome  tag1   tag2    tag3
340      a      b      a
123      a      a       b
23       d      c       b
54       c      a       c
```

I would like to unstack the dataset by creating rows from the column values (a, b, c..) and the relative outcome value, something like:

```
tag outcome
a   340
a   123
a   54
b   340
b   124
b   23
c   23
d   54
```

How?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check my answer if working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
In [321]: (df.set_index('outcome').unstack()
             .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
             .sort_values()
             .reset_index(name='tag')
             .drop_duplicates())
Out[321]:
    outcome tag
0       340   a
1       123   a
3        54   a
5       340   b
6       123   b
7        23   b
8        54   c
9        23   c
11       23   d
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I have some rows with NaN but I cannot seem to drop them using df = df[(df.tag!=np.NaN)], why?

Comment: @FilippoSebastio - `nan`s are special values, check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing), for remove them is best use `df = df.dropna(subset=['tag'])` or if want filtering `df[(df.tag.notnull())]`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df1 = (df.melt('outcome', value_name='tag')
      .sort_values('tag')
      .drop('variable', axis=1)
      .dropna(subset=['tag'])
      .drop_duplicates()[['tag','outcome']])
```

**Explanation**:

1. Reshape by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)
2. Change order by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)
3. Remove column by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
4. Remove possible missing values by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)
5. Last remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Or:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('outcome')
       .stack()
       .sort_values()
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .reset_index(name='tag')
       .drop_duplicates()[['tag','outcome']])
```

**Explanation**:

1. Reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
2. `Series` is sorted by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html)
3. Double [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - first remove level 1 and then create column form index
4. Last remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

---

```
print (df1)
   tag  outcome
0    a      340
1    a      123
7    a       54
4    b      340
9    b      123
10   b       23
3    c       54
6    c       23
2    d       23
```